# AppleScript to raise a window in another space/desktop

Tags: applescript

I am trying to switch between windows in different desktops with AppleScript.
I have 2 Chrome windows opened in 2 different desktops (Desktop 2 & 3). I am able to see properties and indices of both windows with `tell application "Google Chrome" to get properties of windows` but I can only raise the one in the desktop that I am in (Desktop 2) with this code:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
end tell
```

Output from `tell application "Google Chrome" to get properties of windows`:

```applescript
{{closeable:true, zoomed:true, active tab index:1, class:window, index:1, visible:true, name:"YouTube", miniaturizable:true, mode:"normal", active tab:tab id 477 of window id 476 of application "Google Chrome", id:476, miniaturized:false, resizable:true, bounds:{1280, -255, 3200, 800}, zoomable:true}, {closeable:true, zoomed:true, active tab index:1, class:window, index:2, visible:true, name:"Facebook", miniaturizable:true, mode:"normal", active tab:tab id 482 of window id 481 of application "Google Chrome", id:481, miniaturized:false, resizable:true, bounds:{1280, -255, 3200, 800}, zoomable:true}}
```

Is there a way to raise the window in the other space directly? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm offering this as a *workaround* as it does work in a simple two normal *window* configuration where there is one *window* on each **Desktop**, and is executed from **Desktop 1**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set minimized of window 2 to true
    set minimized of window 2 to false
end tell
```

Note that this does cause seeing the *window* from **Desktop 2** be minimized and restored as if on **Desktop 1** but *window* 2 is then frontmost on **Desktop 2** without having switched **Spaces**.

The was tested in a single display multiple **Desktop** scenario under **macOS Catalina**.  Other versions of **macOS** and or **Display** configuration may present differing results.

Comment: Thanks. It does work on Big Sur but it would have to work on Desktop 2 and 3 as well (just edited the question). This is an interesting workaround that could be useful in other situations though.

Comment: @llo, Just tested in a three **Desktop** scenario under **macOS Catalina** using **2** & **3** and running the _code_ from **2** it works on **3** just as in my original answer.  Are you saying it doesn't work in **macOS Big Sur**?

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked in Big Sur! Thanks for helping!