# Raising a window using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, accessibility

I'm trying to bring *one window* forward on a mac using AppleScript. Using `activate` brings *every* window in the app to the front - I want to bring a *single* window to the front.

There are plenty of great answers online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042564/applescript-to-raise-a-window-in-another-space-desktop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173514/applescript-bring-window-to-foreground), for example), and they all suggest using `AXRaise`.

The problem is, it only works for me intermitently. Here's a minimal example

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell (first process whose name is "Google Chrome") to set front_window to window 1
    perform action "AXRaise" of front_window
end tell
```

This *should* find the first Google chrome window and bring it to the front *without* bringing other Chrome windows to the front, and I'd say around 40% of the time it works. The remaining 60% of the time, no dice, and for the life of me I can't figure out why it works in some cases and not others...

Any ideas?

Thanks a million!!